# float(0.0) vs 0.0f in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, floating-point, double, precision

I want to write code valid for both float and double precision.
I am doing something like this:

```
typedef real float;
//typedef real double;

__global__ void foo(real a, real *b){
  b[0] = real(0.5)*a;
}

int main(){
  real a = 1.0f;
  real *b;
  cudaMalloc(&f, sizeof(real));
  foo<<<1,1>>>(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

This got me thinking, I don't want to loose precision in the constant as 0.5f when doing double precision, but I don't want to promote 0.5 to double when doing single precision!

So I ended up using the operator real() as in the example.
In single precision mode, If I disassemble the function 'foo' using real(0.5) I get that there is no promotion to double, as opposed to using just 0.5, where promotion happens.

You can check using:

```
$nvcc test.cu -arch=sm_52 -lineinfo --source-in-ptx -g -G -O0 ; cuobjdump -sass  a.out | grep "foo" -A 35
```

I see

```
/*0078*/                   FMUL R0, R0, 0.5;               /* 0x3868004000070000 */
```

When using real(0.5) or 0.5f
And:

```
/*0078*/                   F2F.F64.F32 R4, R0;           /* 0x5ca8000000070b04 */
/*0088*/                   DMUL R4, R4, 0.5;               /* 0x3880004000070404 */
/*0090*/                   F2F.F32.F64 R0, R4;           /* 0x5ca8000000470e00 */
```

When writing just 0.5.

This may sound too obvious. But as I do not know what is "real(0.5)" doing I cannot know if this is just the compiler playing along in this very particular case. The disassembled code seems identical in both real(0.5) and 0.5f!

**So the question remains:**

**What is real(0.5) (AKA float(0.5)) exactly doing?**

**Is there any difference between float(0.5) and 0.5f? (OR double(0.5) and 0.5)**

This applies to C/C++ as well, I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What is real(0.5) (AKA float(0.5)) exactly doing?

`real(0.5)` [function-style cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), and in this case it lowers to `static_cast`

```
real(0.5)
static_cast<real>(0.5) //exactly the same thing
```

This means `a` is multiplied with a `real` variable (in this case `float`), meaning that there's no need to perform promotion to `double`, as would be the case for `double * float` multiplication.

## Is there any difference between float(0.5) and 0.5f? (OR double(0.5) and 0.5)

One could argue that initialization of `float` with `0.5` could happen at runtime, but this isn't realistic for any modern compiler. It should be a no-op, it already is for the OP.

Other than that, using `float(0.5f)` is makes no difference whatsoever from just using `0.5f`, and the same goes for `double(0.5)` and `0.5`.

Comment: From the reference: 1) If there is an implicit conversion sequence from expression to new_type, or if overload resolution for a direct initialization of an object or reference of type new_type from expression would find at least one viable function, then static_cast<new_type>(expression) returns the imaginary variable Temp initialized as if by new_type Temp(expression);, which may involve implicit conversions, a call to the constructor of new_type or a call to a user-defined conversion operator.

Comment: Doesnt this suggest that static_cast<real>(0.5) is calling real(0.5)?

Also, "[static_cast] may involve implicit conversions, a call to the constructor of new_type or a call to a user-defined conversion operator.". So this is doing something at runtime as opposed to 0.5f?

Comment: If you had more complex types there (with a constructor), then it might have. In your case, though, you can easily see that nothing like that happens. You're initializing `real` with value `0.5`. The compiler knows how to do this at the compile time, and then it's not forced to generate promotion to double to perform multiplication.

Comment: In other words, float(0.5) and 0.5f should generate the same code exactly?

Comment: @Apo I don't think this is *guaranteed*. But if there was a compiler dumb enough not to do such trivial optimization, you shouldn't use it. I'm confident it's safe will always do the right thing for you to use `real(0.5)` here to disambiguate between `float` and `double`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: expanded the answer. Do you find it more acceptable now?

Comment: Not really. The question asks about `float(0.5)` vs `0.5f`.

Comment: @krzaq Ok, so this is not something like:
1)I have a double, 0.5.
2)Send it to the function "float" that takes a double and returns a float.
3)Operate with that float.

--This is more like the compiler taking 0.5 and using it as a float in the first place? So you say float(0.5) and the compiler stores something like 0.5000000GIBERISH

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry to ping you again - how about now?

Comment: @Apo yes, seeing that it's used to initialize a `float` the compiler generates `0.5f` directly. It's not required to do so, but all reasonable compilers do this.

Comment: @Apo play around with different compilers [here](https://godbolt.org/g/TVAFvu). They should generate identical code for `foo` and `bar` consistently. Note the `-O0` meaning lowest optimization level.

Comment: @krzaq Cool page! thanks, definitely helps!
Thank you very much guys!
I think this is solved now

Comment: @Patrick absolutely right, I meant the float representation of 0.5 instead of the double representation of 0.5.